# why is it "one European institution", but "European Institutions" (with capital i) if talking about several authorities?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

I found this spelling differentiation on the website of the EU commission and you can see it on wikipedia, too:

"There are a range of European Institutions in Strasbourg (France), the oldest of which dates back to 1815."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_institutions_in_Strasbourg

If someone could point out the grammatical base of this differentiation, I would appreciate that!

Many thanks,
Alexandra

Comment: the examples are meaningless.  there's is no "definitive," "authorised" way to write it.  I personally would always just use lower-case.  the fact that you've found examples each way means nothing - English is, generally, very erratic and badly written.

Comment: EU does have rules for every such style thing, see for instance http://www.etf.europa.eu/authorssite.nsf?OpenDatabase&Content=http://www.etf.europa.eu/authorssite.nsf/Pages/Capital+letters+and+small+letters+%E2%80%93+Upper+case+and+lower+case?OpenDocument and http://ec.europa.eu/translation/english/guidelines/documents/styleguide_english_dgt_en.pdf

Comment: I would underscore @JoeBlow's comment by noting that Wikipedia is a particularly poor source for authoritative style examples.  People from all over the world with different educational backgrounds edit the articles.  Frequently you can find capitalization and punctuation that comply with style rules from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of singular vs. plural; it is a matter of whether you are talking about just some institution that is situated in Europe, or an institution that is actually *named* “European Institution”—and multiple institutions might well share that name.

In the case of the Wikipedia article, the capitalization seems random. In the case of the EU Commission site, the plural with both elements capitalized appears to be a plural proper name referring to a finite set of official EU bodies: the European Parliament, the Council of the European Union, the European Commission, the Court of Justice of the EU, and the Court of Auditors. But that site too seems to vary randomly between capitalizing and not capitalizing *institutions* even in that context.